# Partial and text field in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have such partial in my rails app (using haml markup):

```
%p
    = line_item.ART_ID
    &times
    = line_item.quantity
    = line_item.total_price
```

But i want to edit using ajax this line_item.quantity field, using Text Fields from html, but how to do this correctly, so that textfield value must be line_item.quantity ? I tried all for simple views, but not partials...

Comment: what's exactly your problem? Just the using text field or the ajax call too?

Answer (score 1):

```
= %input{ :value => line_item.quantity }
```

That will create an  tag with an initial value of the quantity. You could also do it with the text_field helper from rails, but they accomplish the same thing. To edit it with ajax you would probably want to give it an ID

```
= %input#someID{ :value => line_item.quantity }
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the percent signs.

Comment: %input{ :value => line_item.quantity } thats ok